# Group By Taxonomy term on view but show all articles containing it

Tags: 7, views

I am trying to generate a view that groups nodes by a taxonomy attached to them but only shows the Taxonomy term once then all the titles under it.

Term 1 
Article
Article 
Article 
Article

Term 2 
Article 
Article

Term 3 
Article 
Article 
Article

An example of what im trying to solve.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my example I have *Article* with *taxonomy term reference field* **tags** and have create following content/terms

- 2 Tags: test1, test2
- 4 articles (2 including test1, 2 including test2)

Create a view of content displaying fields and filter to display articles only

- add title field
- add tag field (can exclude it from display)
- format settings > choose grouping field Nr 1. > tags

[image]
[image]